# Detect the selected value in a select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making a registration form that inserts the data in a DB but I get stuck in this

```
<select class="input-25" name="Genero">
    <option value="1">Masculino</option> 
    <option value="2">Femenino</option>
</select>
```

My question is:

> How do I detect which option the user chooses, if the value 1 or 2 to later insert it into the db

This is the method I use for email for example

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo" class="input-80" required>
```

Then in another file or this happens:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

Comment: `$gender = $_POST['Genero'];`

Comment: Is the detention of 1 or 2 automatic?

Comment: If you selected `Masculino` the value `1` will be sent to the server.

Comment: are you using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

We can get the selected value of `select` `box` by this in php -

```
    <?php
  echo $_POST['Genero'];
    ?>
```